How to find all simple paths of no more than k lengths starting at a vertex in a directed graph?
I am trying to find all simple paths up to a given length, and working on using BFS to solve this problem. However, I am not sure about the specific algorithm to use. It seems that BFS cannot easily solve this problem. All problems I found were about finding paths between two given vertexes.
However, I wonder how to find all simple paths that have lengths up to a given k, starting at a given vertex in a directed graph. No cycles are allowed.
k lengths means k hops, not the weights of paths.

For example, we have k = 3, and given vertex 1, we want to find paths of length of k = 1, k = 2, k = 3.
when k = 1, we have paths 12 and 13; when k = 2, we have paths 132 and 134; when k = 3, we don't find appropriate paths.
What algorithm can I use to solve the problem?

@trincot Your suggestion is very helpful. I will post a new question about the added content!

You would use a depth-first traversal for this. A recursive function is the natural choice for that. It would recur up to depth k and then produce the path it had traversed. At each recursive call make sure you don't add a node to the path that is already on the path. And when you get out of a recursive call, reduce the path accordingly.
Here is an implementation in JavaScript, where the recursive function takes as argument an adjacency list (to represent the graph), the current node, the value of k and the path as a Set (an ordered Hash Set).


function* genPaths(adj, node, k, path=new Set) {
    if (path.has(node)) return; // cycle detected!
    if (k == 0) return yield [...path, node]; // We have a result
    path.add(node);
    for (const neighbor of adj[node]) {
        yield* genPaths(adj, neighbor, k - 1, path);
    }
    path.delete(node); // backtrack
}

// Demo
const adj = {
    "1": ["2", "3"],
    "2": [],
    "3": ["2", "4"],
    "4": ["3"]
};

// Finding paths with k=1, k=2 and k=3:
for (let k = 1; k <= 3; k++) {
    console.log("results for k =", k);
    for (const path of genPaths(adj, "1", k)) {
        console.log("  ", ...path);
    }
}
console.log("done");



Extending it...
The above function returns paths of exactly k lengths, and the main code uses it to get paths for several different lengths. If you are always interested in all shorter paths as well, even including the one with size 0 (just the starting node) then you could extend the function to do that all with one top-level call:


function* genPaths(adj, node, k, path=new Set) {
    if (path.has(node)) return; // cycle detected!
    yield [...path, node]; // We have a result (0 <= path size <= k)
    if (k == 0) return;
    path.add(node);
    for (const neighbor of adj[node]) {
        yield* genPaths(adj, neighbor, k - 1, path);
    }
    path.delete(node); // backtrack
}

// Demo
const adj = {
    "1": ["2", "3"],
    "2": [],
    "3": ["2", "4"],
    "4": ["3"]
};

// Finding paths with size <= 3:
for (const path of genPaths(adj, "1", 3)) {
    console.log("  ", ...path);
}
console.log("done");



Note that the size of a path is expressed as the number of edges on it, so  [1] is a path of length 0, [1, 3] is a path of length 1, ...etc.
If you want to exclude the path with length 0, then just add a condition to the yield statement:
    if (path.length > 0) yield [...path, node];


Hey, thanks! It is very helpful! My graph is really big. If we use DFS/recursion, it may cause a stack overflow. Can I use BFS?

The maximum recursion depth is equal to k, the maximum path length.

@beaker You are right. I got it! Thanks!

I consider DFS more suitable for this than BFS. Is this eventually what you are looking for? Let me know if you still have a doubt...

@trincot I think the main disadvantage of DFS lies in its duplicate calculation. For example, the paths of k = 1 are the prefix paths of k = 2. If we calculate the paths separately for k = 1, 2, and 3, it is not that efficient. Right?

@trincot Oh after I replied to you I immediately saw the latest edited answer! It is just what I want. Thanks a lot! It is very nice of you!

@trincot I implemented both BFS and DFS. I found that BFS is much quicker than DFS!

That would be surprising, as in general it needs much more memory allocations. If you want me to verify, feel free to post your work in an answer.

@trincot Hi, I added my code to the question just now.

Here is pseudo code for Yen's algorithm
IMPORT graph, source and sink
CLEAR vShortestPaths
calculate shortest path from source to sink, add to vShortestPaths
WHILE TRUE
   CLEAR vPotentialPaths
   SET work = graph
   LOOP PF over vShortestPaths
       LOOP spur over PF
            REMOVE out edge from spur in work used by PF
            calculate spurPath, shortest path from spur to sink in work
            IF spurPath exists
                CONTINUE to next iteration of LOOP spur
            SET newPath to combination of source to spur in PF and spurPath
            IF newPath NOT in vShortestPaths
                ADD newPath to vPotentialPaths
            END LOOP spur
        END LOOP PF
    IF vPotentialPaths NOT empty
        ADD shortest path in vPotentialPaths to vShortestPaths
    END WHILE TRUE 

To find all the paths in a graph:
Set vertices into fixed order ( input order is fine )
LOOP I over vertices
   LOOP J over the (J+1)the to the last vertex
       Apply Yen to I,J vertex pair


Thanks! However, this algorithm considers the weights of paths. The "length" in my question is equal to the hops of a path, not the weights.

Set the weights to 1 for every edge.

I just found that the input of this algorithm needs the origin vertex and the destination vertex, which is different from my question.

Loop over the unique vertex pairs and apply Yen's algorithm to each.

Yen's algorithm is used to calculate the k-shortest paths. That is a completely different problem than the one posed by the OP.

The OP wants all the paths up to a a given length.  Yen returns the paths between two vertices in order of increasing length.  Filter out the paths that are longer than required and loop over unique vertex pairs.  Then the OP's problem is solved. I imagined these steps to apply the algorithm to this particular problem would be obvious.  It is a very basic skill to apply the standard algorithms to slightly different problems - otherwise you will always be reinventing the wheel to build different wagons.

Yes, I see the modifications necessary to make this work, but my question is why? You're answering a simple problem by solving a more complex problem many times. That "calculate shortest path" step, how is that implemented? Probably with Dijkstra's, right? So each execution of Dijkstra's, you're calculating the shortest path from one source to all other vertices in the remaining graph, and then throwing them all away except for one. Then re-executing until the path becomes too long. Then re-executing all of that for every sink. But what is Dijkstra's algorithm on unweighted graphs? DFS.

A backtracking* version of the DFS traversal used by Goodrich, Tamassia & Goldwasser (2013) in Section 14.3.1 - 14.3.2, can be modified and adapted to solve this problem.
We also want to keep track of visited vertices and corresponding tree edges (or discovery edges) by the use of an ordered Hash Table (which implies your vertex must be hashable), which therein prevents cyclic traversal (by using an Adjacency Map to represent the Graph, we can query traversed vertices in O(1) time and omit back edges).
This will ultimately produce the (implied) strongly connected components (or connected components in the case of an undirected graph) reachable by traversing at most k-1 edges in the graph, by invoking DFS on a starting vertex s, and then recursively calling DFS on all incidental discovery edge vertices at the specified k-range.
* We populate a concurrent path accumulator for every valid recursive DFS call (when traversed edges < k) , and then backtrack and pop the corresponding retraction edges (triggered when traversed edges >= k, until a new edge is traversed and accumulated again) as the recursion unwinds.

The following solution uses an Adjacency Map representation of a Graph as presented by Goodrich et al. (pp. 635-637). For brevity, the Graph implementation which is 100% compatible with this algorithm with zero dependencies can be found here: graph.py.
Methods Graph.insert_vertex(), Graph.insert_edge(), Edge.opposite(), Edge.endpoints() all run in O(1) time, except Graph.incident_edges(v) which takes O(outgoing-degree(v)) time.
Initially, klen_dfs() ought to take O(n) time at the worst case (when finding a vertex reachable in k edges requires traversing the whole graph). However, saving each unique path (with the line path_array.append(p[:])) incites some necessary recomputation amassing to approximately summation(k) operations per each k-length path traversed, that is nk × summation(k), where nk is the number of vertices reachable by traversing k edges. Overall, klen_dfs() takes O((nk× k2) + n) time in worst case.
from collections import OrderedDict
from typing import List
from graph import Graph


def init_graph():
    G = Graph(directed=True)

    v1 = G.insert_vertex(1)
    v2 = G.insert_vertex(2)
    v3 = G.insert_vertex(3)
    v4 = G.insert_vertex(4)

    G.insert_edge(v1, v2)
    G.insert_edge(v1, v3)
    G.insert_edge(v3, v2)
    G.insert_edge(v3, v4)
    G.insert_edge(v4, v3)

    return G, v1


def klen_dfs(G: Graph, s: Graph.Vertex, k: int):
    """Report all paths (edge lists) less than length k.
    G - Adjacency Map Graph ADT
    s - Starting vertex
    k - Path length limit (actual limit = k-1)
    """
    discovery_edges: OrderedDict[Graph.Vertex, Graph.Edge] = OrderedDict()
    path_accummulator: List[Graph.Edge] = [ ]
    path_array: List[List[Graph.Edge]] = [ ]

    def dfs(g: Graph, u: Graph.Vertex, discovered, klen, p):
        """Traditional DFS with addtional params.
        u - A vertex in G
        p - Concurrent path array of less than k edges
        """
        if klen < k:
            for e in g.incident_edges(u, outgoing=True):
                v = e.opposite(u)
                if not discovered.get(v):   # Cyclic traversal prevention
                    discovered[v] = e
                    p.append(e)
                    path_array.append(p[:])
                    dfs(g, v, discovered, klen + 1, p)
                    p.pop()
                    discovered.pop(v)

    dfs(G, s, discovery_edges, 1, path_accummulator)
    return path_array


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # For graph produced by init_graph(), all k >= 3 has same results
    for K in range(1,4):
        digraph, start = init_graph()
        paths = klen_dfs(digraph, start, K)
        formatted_paths = []
        for path in paths:
            formatted_path = []
            for edge in path:
                endpoints = edge.endpoints()
                formatted_path.append((
                    endpoints[0].element(), endpoints[1].element()))
            formatted_paths.append(formatted_path)
        print(f"ALL paths when k = {K} (i.e of length {K-1} < k length)")
        print(*formatted_paths, sep="\n")
        print()

Output:
ALL paths when k = 1 (i.e of length 0 < k length)

ALL paths when k = 2 (i.e of length 1 < k length)
[(1, 2)]
[(1, 3)]

ALL paths when k = 3 (i.e of length 2 < k length)
[(1, 2)]
[(1, 3)]
[(1, 3), (3, 2)]
[(1, 3), (3, 4)]

Visualization of simple valid paths less than length k=3 when s=1

Other considerations: strictly k-length paths
Following the modifications to trincot's answer, we can otherwise choose to report only those paths whose lengths are of size k by replacing the line in the nested dfs() function: path_array.append(p[:]) with if klen == k-1: path_array.append(p[:]).
This reduces the time complexity from O((nk× k2) + n) to O((nk× k) + n), and produces the following output:
ALL paths when k = 1 (i.e of length 0 < k length)

ALL paths when k = 2 (i.e of length 1 < k length)
[(1, 2)]
[(1, 3)]

ALL paths when k = 3 (i.e of length 2 < k length)
[(1, 3), (3, 2)]
[(1, 3), (3, 4)]


Thanks a lot! I need to take time to understand the code because I haven't used Python for a long time.
